# Macro to apply formula in the first active cell

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change this Macro so that after it filters in CR it will select the first active cell to enter/use the formula given without specifying a cell number since the cell number may change from one file to another.

```
Range("D5").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$2232").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="CR"
Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[2]"
Range("D3").Select
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("E3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]"
Range("D9").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws  As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Range("D5").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="CR"
ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[2]"
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]"
```

Comment: Thank you Bruno, but it didn't work.

Comment: Insert the code after the line ("ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Select")

Do While ActiveCell <> "" '0
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop